# android: remove padding from linearlayout to create square layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to create a chess game board with 8x8 buttons. I'm using nested LinearLayouts. The problem is that there's a padding between each row of ImageViews that I can't get rid of. This is what I have sofar, the board should be square, but isn't:

[image]

```
public class BoardLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public BoardLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

            setLayoutParams(parms);
            setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(context);
                row.setLayoutParams(parms);
                row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                row.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    ImageView button = new ImageView(context);
                    button.setLayoutParams(parms);
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                    button.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    row.addView(button);
                }
                addView(row);
            }
            setSquare();
    }
    public void setSquare() {
        int size = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());

        // setHeight(size); // Not Function, but this is what I need
        // setWidth(size); // Not Function, but this is what I need

        // also doesn't work
        setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, size, 1.0f));
    }
}
```

---

**Solution:**

As suggested TableLayout is better for what I'm trying to do. So the main class should be changed to a TableLayout and the nested LinearLayouts to TableRows.

But that alone didn't fix it, I also had to call the following in TableLayout:

```
setShrinkAllColumns(true);
setStretchAllColumns(true);
```

and for each item inserted, I had to also call:

```
setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)
>
> **Class Overview**
>
> A layout that arranges its children
>   into rows and columns. A TableLayout
>   consists of a number of TableRow
>   objects, each defining a row
>   (actually, you can have other
>   children, which will be explained
>   below). TableLayout containers do not
>   display border lines for their rows,
>   columns, or cells.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a GridView or TableLayout instead of nested LinearLayouts, since that's what they're designed for.